# ArcMap ModelBuilder Date query in line substition

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, datetime

[image]

[image]

I have successfully created the Minimum date and time variable as well as the maximum date and time variable(date datatype). I am only looking 30 seconds in either direction from the record I am querying. My problem is when I try to do an in line substation for the select layer by attribute it will not accept `[Date_stamp] >= %#Min_Query#%` it says there was a syntax error. The field I am querying is a date and time field and the variable I am using is a date time variable. Both appear to always have an associated time. I added a picture to show exact formats.

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

Comment: When you reference a variable it is between `%` not `%#` so it should be `%Min_Query%`.

Comment: I read elsewhere that dates are treated differently. However I get the same syntax error with ([Date_stamp] >= %Min_Query%). I get a data mismatch with ([RoundTime_UTC] >= '%Min_Query%') and ('[RoundTime_UTC] >= '%#Min_Quer#y%')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you process date time values is dependant on your database format. Here is a test model:

[image: Model]

I use the Calculate Value tool to create a `datetime` object:

[image: Calculate Value]

In the Select Layer by attribute tool the expression is:

`dt > date '%dt%'`

In a file geodatabase you need to place the word date before your quoted inline substitution variable.

This creates a selection based upon a field called `dt` in a layer.

[image: Selected]

Comment: I tried to recreate your attribute query but, '[RoundTime_UTC] <=  date '%Nowtime%'', my field name has brackets around it. I am using a personal geodatabase and not a file geodatabase. I do not know if that makes a difference. When I got to verify it says missing operator.

Comment: Check out the help file [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-85C03D85-F4A5-48FC-8E8C-3F79919430DB).

Comment: May it should be something like: `[RoundTime_UTC] <= #%Nowtime%#` ?